# Material UI with React: How to style <Autocomplete/> with rounded corners

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I've always been a fan of Google's search bar, with nice rounded corners and ample padding around the text.

[image]

I'm trying to replicate this style using Material UI's `<Autocomplete/>` component, but I can't seem to do it. I'm using Next.js. What I have so far is:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import { borderRadius, Box } from '@mui/system';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';


const LiveSearch = (props) => {

  const [jsonResults, setJsonResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => setJsonResults(json));
  }, []);

  return (
      <Stack sx={{ width: 400, margin: "auto"}}>
        <Autocomplete
          id="Hello"
          getOptionLabel={(jsonResults) => jsonResults.name}
          options={jsonResults}
          noOptionsText="No results"
          isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
            option.name === value.name
          }}
          renderOption={(props, jsonResults) => (
            <Box component="li" {...props} key={jsonResults.id}>
              {jsonResults.name} - Ahhh
            </Box>
          )}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Search users..." />}
        />
                  

      </Stack>

  )
}

export default LiveSearch;
```

The above code should run as-is – there's an axios call in there to populate the autocomplete results too.

[image]

I've tried various way to get the `<SearchIcon />` icon prefix inside the input with no success, but really I'd just be happy if I could figure out how to pad it. You can see in the google screenshot how the autocomplete lines up really well with the box, but in my version, the border-radius just rounds the element, and so it no longer lines up with the dropdown.

I'm new to Material UI, so I'm still not quite sure how to do these styles, but I think the issue is that the border is being drawn by some internal element, and although I can set the borderRadius on the component itself global CSS:

```css
.MuiOutlinedInput-root {
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

I can't seem to set the padding or borders anywhere. I've also tried setting style with `sx` but it does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look at the [autocomplete css](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#css) classes and override them in your component or use them in [your theme](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides), if you use one.

```
<Autocomplete
    componentsProps={{
      paper: {
        sx: {
          width: 350,
          margin: "auto"
        }
      }
    }}
    id="Hello"
    notched
    getOptionLabel={(jsonResults) => jsonResults.name}
    options={jsonResults}
    noOptionsText="No results"
    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
      option.name === value.name;
    }}
    renderOption={(props, jsonResults) => (
      <Box component="li" {...props} key={jsonResults.id}>
        {jsonResults.name} - Ahhh
      </Box>
    )}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        label="Search users..."
        sx={{
          "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
            borderRadius: "50px",

            legend: {
              marginLeft: "30px"
            }
          },
          "& .MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot": {
            paddingLeft: "20px !important",
            borderRadius: "50px"
          },
          "& .MuiInputLabel-outlined": {
            paddingLeft: "20px"
          },
          "& .MuiInputLabel-shrink": {
            marginLeft: "20px",
            paddingLeft: "10px",
            paddingRight: 0,
            background: "white"
          }
        }}
      />
    )}
  />
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-field-qsstrs?file=/src/Search.js

Comment: I've tried those, and adding that class to globals.css did nothing. I'm probably just implementing it wrong, so some code would be really helpful.

Comment: Added an example for the padding

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful but I'm still a very long way from getting it :(

Comment: You could create a sandbox and share the link. This example would work on mui v5

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-bhabha-vkefqk?file=/src/Search.js

Comment: Your sandbox is straight from the docs, identical to my starting point. But now that you have it, try to extend out the edges and round them, (i.e. try to mimic the google styling), and you'll see the issue I've been having.

Comment: I had added the left padding. I also added the other styling and the width you wanted for the dropdown https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-field-qsstrs?file=/src/Search.js

Answer (score 2):

<s>I'm trying to figure out how to line up the edges</s> *(figured it out, see update)*, but this is how I was able to insert the Search icon, via `renderInput` and I got rid of the expand and collapse arrows at the end of the bar by setting `freeSolo={true}` (but this allows user input to not be bound to provided options).

```js
import { Search } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { Autocomplete, AutocompleteRenderInputParams, InputAdornment } from '@mui/material';

...
<Autocomplete
            freeSolo={true}
            renderInput={(renderInputParams: AutocompleteRenderInputParams) => (
                <div ref={renderInputParams.InputProps.ref}
                    style={{
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        width: '100%',
                        display: 'flex',
                        flexDirection: 'row'
                    }}>
                    <TextField style={{ flex: 1 }} InputProps={{
                        ...renderInputParams.InputProps, startAdornment: (<InputAdornment position='start'> <Search /> </InputAdornment>),
                    }}
                        placeholder='Search'
                        inputProps={{
                            ...renderInputParams.inputProps
                        }}
                        InputLabelProps={{ style: { display: 'none' } }}
                    />
                </div >
            )}
            ...
/>
```

Ignore the colors and other styling, but this is what it looks like:

[image]

### Update

I was able to line up the edges by controlling the `border-radius` via css and setting the bottom left and right to 0 and top ones to 20px.

Here's a demo:

[image: Demo of Mui Autocomplete acting like Google search]

Here are the changes I had to make in css. I also left the bottom border so there is a division between the search and the results, but you can style if however you like. (Also I'm using scss so I declared colors as variables at the top).

```css
div.MuiAutocomplete-root div.MuiOutlinedInput-root { /* Search bar when not in focus */
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: $dark-color;
}

div.MuiAutocomplete-root div.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused { /* Search bar when focused */
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px !important;
}

div.MuiAutocomplete-root div.Mui-focused fieldset { /* fieldset element is what controls the border color. Leaving only the bottom border when dropdown is visible */
  border-width: 1px !important;
  border-color: transparent transparent $light-gray-color transparent !important;
}

.MuiAutocomplete-listbox { /* To control the background color of the listbox, which is the dropdown */
  background-color: $dark-color;
}

div.MuiAutocomplete-popper div { /* To get rid of the rounding applied by Mui-paper on the dropdown */
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply add border radius to fieldset:

```
<Autocomplete
  sx={{ '& fieldset': { borderRadius: 33 }}}
/>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocompete-rounded-corners-d45q9l?file=/demo.tsx)